# Configuring nginx proxy for rstudio to work through ssh tunnel

Tags: nginx, proxy, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, rstudio-server

We installed rstudio in a docker container and configured it following

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552326-Running-RStudio-Server-with-a-Proxy

In order to use a sub-uri: `example.com/rstudio`. This is a work situation, and the server `example.com` is behind a firewall. To access websites behind the wall I typically tunnel like

```
ssh -L 8000:example.com:80 other_server
```

When I do this for `example.com` I can load pages like `example.com/test.html`. However, when I try `localhost:8000/rstudio`, it maps me right back to `example.com/rstudio`.

Is there something I could add to the configuration in the linked docs page that would make things work through the tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you quick&dirty hack:

1. Add example.com = 127.0.0.1 at your local PC
2. ssh -L 8000:remote_server_ip:80 other_server
3. Try go to http://example.com/rstudio

It can be caused by mod_rewrite of your rstudio instance I think

Look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/things-to-do-with-ssh-ssh-tunneling.html) for more examples of SSH tunneling, maybe it will help too.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by >add example.com = 127.0.0.1 at your local PC? Add to what?

Comment: Add it to your local hosts file, sorry